# generating street map from openstreetmap dat through osm2wkt

Tags: openstreetmap, wkt

i am trying to generate street map of a city from openstreetmap data. i have used osm2wkt tool but it converts it into wkt file. is there any way to convert in map rather than in wkt file.

Comment: actually i am trying to generate map as given on this site tm.kit.edu/~mayer/osm2wkt .

Answer (score 0):

A printed map? An online "slippy" map?

Obviously osm2wkt is not the tool you want if you don't want wkt.

To custom-design your own online slippy maps you can use [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/).

If you just want to get a PNG or SVG or PDF of one place, you can just go to http://www.openstreetmap.org/ , browse to the place you want, and use the "Export" tab.

Comment: i want to generate map for a city like it is given on http://www.tm.kit.edu/~mayer/osm2wkt/ . there it is written it is generated through osm2wkt. you please see the link.

Comment: anyone please reply how the street map generated on osm2wkt site.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the osm2wkt site you can use [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/) to visualise WKT data.  You can find a tutorial (PDF) [here](http://www.boutique-geomarketing.fr/webContent/telechargements/openjump/OpenJUMP1.0.1_Tutorial_englishBeta.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

First, go to http://www.openstreetmap.org/ and select the coordinates of the area you want. Then, choose export . It will give some file in .osm format like map.osm.
 Now we have to convert the map.osm file to map.wkt file. Use osm2wkt jar for that purpose. Download that jar file from http://www.tm.kit.edu/~mayer/osm2wkt/.

Now, use the following command.

```
java -jar osm2wkt.jar map.osm
```

Now, open the file with OpenJump. And save it in .wkt format by selecting points in the map as you want.